# SSH Online Code Editor Terminal Security Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, terminal

I am currently going through a tutorial with Ruby On Rails through a third party code editor.
It's currently walking me through through the process of getting my stuff onto a git repository and I have set up an SSH key from within the terminal of the online code editor itself. (not my computers code editor)

Using the command ***cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub***  I accidentally printed it onto the console and am worried about security. It was the only way I could carry on with the tutorial. I did manage to push my application to the repo successfully. Is it wise to generate SSH Keys through other online code editors? Does it matter?

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dan